# Cordova - 'AVAudioSessionDelegateMediaPlayerOnly end interruption' error after pausing and resuming an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, html, cordova

This issue has arose using Cordova to play videos within an iOS application. I had thought to use the pause/resume feature to interact with the HTML5 video. However even when the video has stopped playing and the element has been set to display:none, or faded out etc, this error still appears in the console after the app is resumed - which then renders all video playing useless after it.

> MP AVAudioSessionDelegateMediaPlayerOnly end interruption. Interruptor
>   <***_*__*_*____**-1874> category <(null)> resumable <0>,  _state = 1

I have found issues relating to this, but are answered using C Objective for native app building.. and because I am using Cordova to build they do not apply unfortunately.

Has anyone else playing videos within PhoneGap/Cordova/Chrome Apps come across this and can offer a solution? Or anyone coding Native iOS apps could offer some advice as to why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix this (for anyone who may come across this in the future!), i had to resort to a bit of a hacky method.

When the Cordova iOS app is pushed to the background, and resumed, it looks as though any running video tags were unable to continue load and play video - the error above pops up in Xcode console and the video element is black no matter what. (I was fading still images on top of a video tag, then loading a new video using data attributes after a hotspot on the image is pressed). So when the app is paused I had to use JS/jQuery to remove and on resume it re-creates the video element and used the last selected data attributes to pick up the info from where it left off..

Seems to work, and is surprisngly seamless! :)